# My code don't print the array I send to the fuction

Tags: c, checksum

So I'm trying to make a checksum, and in my code a send a array to get the result of the function but no result show in my printf anyone can help me resolve this, the code is this.(Ps.: the main is just a example.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void getchecksum(char buffer[32][32], char ch3[32]){
    char ch1[32],ch2[32];
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<32;j++){
            ch1[j]=buffer[j][i];
        }
        i++;
        for(int j=0;j<32;j++){
            ch2[j]=buffer[j][i];
            ch2[j]=ch1[j]^ch2[j];
            if(i<2) ch3[j]=ch2[j];
            else ch3[j]=ch3[j]^ch2[j];
        }
    }
}

int main (){
    char temp[32][32],sum[32];
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<32;j++){
            temp[j][i]='a';
        }
    }
    getchecksum(temp,&sum);
    printf("%s", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Tried this too:

```
    getchecksum(temp,sum);
    for(int j=0;j<32;j++){
        printf("%c", sum[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Pay attention to the compiler's warnings. You should get something like `expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[32]’` from the `getchecksum(temp,&sum)` call.

Comment: I tried change it and didn't solve, anything else, I really appreciate help.

Comment: I tried send the array without the &. And tried change the checksum to *ch3, both didn't work.Send the array without the & don't show error but don't print what I want and the *ch3 show almost the same error

Comment: `"%s"` format specifier expects a NUL-terminated string, I see no attempt to terminate it. Furthermore, with all your XORing, do you expect all the resulting characters will be printable? They shouldn't necessarily be, you'd be better off printing each character as a hex byte instead of as a printable C string.

Comment: the print is more to see if the function make the changes, I don't really want to print then, but I'm not sure that the function is making the change and sending it to the main.Like I said it's a checksum I'm using it to check a file transfer but if the function don't make what I want or is causing any error my program don't work, I'm trying to find what in my program don't work and it's looking like is this function.Also just test with %c print char a char and don't print anything.

Comment: `sum` is uninitialized, which is fine if all you're going to do is write to it in the function, but you don't, you use it for the calculation. What is it you expect `sum` to contain after the function call and why?

Comment: I want it have the checksum result, I use it in the function so I don't need to create other variable.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is used for *string literals*. To print the data of a integer `array`, we use a `for` loop.

```
//printf("%s", sum);  // Not this
for(int i=0; i<32; i++) printf("%d ", sum[i]);
```

[Here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/cV23ZBGK6r/) is a fixed version of your code.

Comment: but is a char array, I tried the %c why it didn't work?

Comment: Did you try the [full code](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/cV23ZBGK6r/)? It did work for me.